# Calculate difference of two values in hash

Tags: perl, hash

**Input from file**

```
ID      S1              S2              S3             S4
a     R1  R2          R3  R4          R5  R6         R7  R8
.   .       .   .   .       .
.       .       .       .       .
```

a   is the ID may be string
R1,R2,R3,R4.....are numeric values

I have to use perl script.I have to read the above data from a file and read in hashes.I have to calculate the difference of R1 and R2 if difference is greater than 0 then print R1 and R2 as it is,other put 0 in place of R1 and R2. next find the difference of R3 and R4. How can we do the above problem using hashes

**Output of the perl program:**

```
ID      S1             S2           S3              S4
a     R1  R2          0  0         0  0           R7  R8
.   .       .   .   .       .
.       .       .       .       .
.   .       .       .       .
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need a hash to find the difference of pairs of numbers???

```
print(scalar(<>));

while (<>) {
   my @parts = split ' '; 
   for (my $i=1; $i<@parts; $i+=2) {
      if ($parts[$i+0] == $parts[$i+1]) {
         $parts[$i+0] = '0';
         $parts[$i+1] = '0';
      }
   }

   print(join(' ', @parts), "\n");
}
```

Or if you want to preserve the formatting:

```
print(scalar(<>));

while (<>) {
   chomp;
   my @parts = split /(\s+)/; 
   for (my $i=2; $i<@parts; $i+=4) {
      if ($parts[$i+0] == $parts[$i+2]) {
         $parts[$i+0] = sprintf('%*s',  length($parts[$i+0]), '0');
         $parts[$i+2] = sprintf('%*s', -length($parts[$i+2]), '0');
      }
   }

   print(join('', @parts), "\n");
}
```